# Add pre-processor to Eclipse CDT toolchain

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

Is there a straightforward way to get Eclipse CDT to run the code through a pre-processor before passing through its syntax checker and whatnot to handle auto-correction and in-IDE error checking?

Ideally, if I have a pre-processor that replaces `$foo` with `std::cout`, I could then type `$foo.flu` and then do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> to correctly auto-complete to `$foo.flush()`.

Would this require hacking/extending CDT internally, or is there is a way to configure an existing toolchain to do this? Even if it correctly identifies that `$foo` is not a syntax error without auto-completion, that would help.

Of course the code compiles fine (using a CMake script, not the Eclipse builder), but I'd like to be able to get Eclipse to stop showing a million errors without disabling error checking altogether.

Comment: If there are any other IDEs that can do this seamlessly (such as *Code::Blocks*, etc.), I'm open to suggestions. I'm flexible with the tools that I use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse, as it stands, cannot and will not do this. Other major IDEs follow suit.

The reason for this is because most IDEs ship with a basic or proprietary build system that is meant to integrate seamlessly with the IDE itself.

Most major projects use an IDE almost as an afterthought; code is set up, a dedicated build system is wired up and configured (such as [make](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/), [cmake](http://www.cmake.org), [scons](http://www.scons.org/), [gradle](https://www.gradle.org/), or my personal favorite, [tup](http://gittup.org/tup/)), and then the IDE is brought on to the chain simply as a visual or syntactic aid for a particular developer.

Most (if not all) of the aforementioned build systems support drop-in preprocessors (some are easier than others). Build systems are a dime a dozen and [are quite easy to find](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_build_automation_software).